# Can't use localparam variable as a value

Tags: system-verilog

I have this:

```
localparam A_PARAM = 64;
```

And I want to use it in this:

```
some_register <= A_PARAM'h197;
```

I tried:

```
some_register <= `A_PARAM'h197;
```

But nothing happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Annoyingly that type of syntax is not allowed.

Parameters can be used to specify the width of register or for replication operators.

```
localparam A_PARAM = 64;

reg [A_PARAM-1:0] some_register;

always @* begin
  some_register = { A_PARAM  {1'b1}};
end
```

You could use auto-sizing, you should get a warning if the number you use has been truncated.

```
some_register <= 'h0; //Right Hands side will be sized to match left hand side (some_reg)
```

Comment: I love autosizing (that's what I used before) but I get a warning about a violation of SystemVerilog strong typing rules for enumeration datatypes.

Comment: What happens if I want to assign value (for example) 'h197 with the replication operator?

Comment: what do you mean? Like: `{ {A_PARAM-11 {1'b1}}, {10{1'b0}}, {1{1'b1}}};`? (that whould be devastating)

Comment: sorry was on train, just meant `{'h1234}` might suppress the warning. Have not been able to see these warnings on EDA playground to test it.